# Dynamically created JavaScript code from Code behind not working on javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I searched a lot for my issue but can not find any suitable solution. I have a JavaScript code which have html select statement i would like to add option from code behind

**JavaScript function**

```
function addMoreRows()
{
        rowCount++;
        var recRow = "";
        recRow += '<tr id="rowCount' + rowCount + '">';
        recRow += '<td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">';
        recRow += '<select style="height: 25px; border:0; width:250px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" id="ddl_grid_productList" onchange="addrowswithselect()" data-placeholder="Choose a State...">';

        <%=options%>

        recRow += '</select>';
        recRow += '</td><td style="height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">';
        recRow += '<input type="text" style="height: 25px; border:0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" id="field_one" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12" />';
        recRow += '</td><td style="height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">';
        recRow += '<input type="text" style="height: 25px; border:0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" id="Qty' + rowCount + '" onchange="add(' + rowCount + ')" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12" />';
        recRow += '</td><td style="height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">';
        recRow += '<input type="text" id="Rate' + rowCount + '" onchange="add(' + rowCount + ')" style="height: 25px;border:0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12" />';
        recRow += '</td><td class="hidden-480" style="height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">';
        recRow += '<input id="total' + rowCount + '" type="text" onblur="totalamout(),addrows(this.value);" style="height: 25px;border:0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12" readonly />';
        recRow += '</td></tr>';
        jQuery('#<%=tbdy_addedRows.ClientID%>').append(recRow); 
    }
```

**Aspx CodeBehind**

```
    public string options;
    var pro = (from m in db.products select m).ToList();
    foreach (var item in pro)
            {
                ListItem list = new ListItem();
                list.Value = item.code.Trim();
                list.Text = item.name.Trim();
                options += "recRow += '<option value=\"" + item.code.Trim() + "\">" + item.name.Trim() + "</option>';\n";
            }
```

is there any standard way to do that because source view shows that options fetch correctly but JavaScript not working then.

Comment: what are you trying to do.

Comment: I would work with a <template> element (or a <div style="display:none"> for compatibility, containing the html code. The styles should be shifted into a CSS file. Finally, when addMoreRows is called, ask the backend via XMLHTTPRequest to give the only thing depending from the server - the options - in JSON format (array of name/value-pairs), create a copy of your template and insert the options.

Comment: @Webruster i want to create drop down list which have value and text get from code behind.

Comment: @user3099423 then you could have used the **asp:dropdownlist**  control of asp .net here is tutorial to fill it using **list()** [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/303564/Binding-DropDownList-Using-List-Collection-Enum-an)

Comment: Thanks for the reply@Webruster. acctualy i created grid which auto add rows on click tab and on dropdown selection. so i cant use asp:dropdownlist here in between javasricipt code. so i thought this is the good way to do that. but unfortunatly when string fetch into javascript code javascript will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `[WebMethod]` in the code behind file which builds up a list of select options and call it from javascript using `$.ajax`.

**Code behind:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetOptions()
{
    string options = "<option value='Option1'>Option 1</option><option value='Option2'>Option 2</option>"; 
    return options;
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var rowCount = 0;

            $("#btnAddRow").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AddRowsInJquery.aspx/GetOptions",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var options = data.d;
                        addMoreRows(options);
                    },
                    error: function (errordata) {
                        alert(errordata);
                    }
                });
            });

            function addMoreRows(options) {
                rowCount++;
                var recRow = "";
                recRow += '<tr id="rowCount' + rowCount + '">';
                recRow += '<td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">';
                recRow += '<select style="height: 25px; border:0; width:250px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" id="ddl_grid_productList" onchange="addrowswithselect()" data-placeholder="Choose a State...">';
                recRow += options;
                recRow += '</select>';
                recRow += '</td><td style="height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">';
                recRow += '<input type="text" style="height: 25px; border:0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" id="field_one" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12" />';
                recRow += '</td><td style="height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">';
                recRow += '<input type="text" style="height: 25px; border:0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" id="Qty' + rowCount + '" onchange="add(' + rowCount + ')" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12" />';
                recRow += '</td><td style="height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">';
                recRow += '<input type="text" id="Rate' + rowCount + '" onchange="add(' + rowCount + ')" style="height: 25px;border:0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12" />';
                recRow += '</td><td class="hidden-480" style="height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">';
                recRow += '<input id="total' + rowCount + '" type="text" onblur="totalamout(),addrows(this.value);" style="height: 25px;border:0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12" readonly />';
                recRow += '</td></tr>';
                jQuery('#<%: Table1.ClientID%>').append(recRow);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" id="btnAddRow" />
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableCell>Column 1</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Column 2</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Column 3</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Column 4</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Column 5</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Denis Wessels  for your brief answer. finaly my issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your problem. I can suggest to use unbind & bind event for dynamic control. It will bind your event again and your dynamic control's event will fire.

```js
$("#mycontrol").bind("click", (function () {
 $('span').text(" Clicked");
}));
```